# Testing in Python, make lists without quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to implement unittest in python. I have a list which I need to verify.

Therefore I do

```
self.assertEqual(self.yt.get_videos(), self.videos)
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: [<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) ... != ['<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp)...

First differing element 0:
<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p - Simple>
<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p - Simple>
```

Output of both.

```
>>> pprint(yt.get_videos())
[<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p - Simple>,
 <Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p - Simple>,
 <Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p - N/A>,
 <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p - Baseline>,
 <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p - High>,
 <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p - N/A>]
```

Below list I have formed by my own.

```
>>> pprint(videos)
['<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p - Simple>',
 '<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p - Simple>',
 '<Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p - N/A>',
 '<Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p - Baseline>',
 '<Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p - High>',
 '<Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p - N/A>']
```

How can I define my list to have elements without quotes.

Comment: add output of `type(yt.get_videos()[0])`

Comment: <class 'pytube.models.Video'>

Comment: the first is a list of objects, the second a list of strings. Convert one of the two to make them match

Comment: `map(str, yt.get_videos())`

Comment: Unless this is a test for the `__repr__` implementation, it seems like a bad idea. You should check actual property values of your object instead.

Answer (score 0):

the first is a list of objects, the second a list of strings.

Convert one of the two to make them match.

Probably the easiest is to convert them in the test:

```
self.assertEqual([str(el) for el in self.yt.get_videos()], self.videos)
```

or, as @Peter Wood points out

```
self.assertEqual(map(str, self.yt.get_videos()), self.videos)
```

Of course you need to define the `__str__`/`__repr__` methods in your class for `str` to work, and their output must match the format of the strings.

Please see [this SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for more info about `str` and `repr`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to check in your test? That the videos are identical (may be unlikely depending on how they are generating - even videos that look identical may differ, just one pixel being slightly of in color in one frame makes a difference) or that only their string representations are identical?

For the first case you need to have a list of video objects, not just their string representation.

For the second case which is much simpler you don't want to convert the `self.videos` to an "array without quotes". You want to convert the first, like:

```
self.assertEqual([str(v) for v in self.yt.get_videos()], self.videos)
```

Note that this will only check that the string representation matches. For example the first will only be a check that it's a MPEG-4 gp3 video, but not that it's content actually matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare:

```
self.assertEqual([str(el) for el in self.yt.get_videos()], self.videos)
```

And check *repr* method [**`here`**](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/models.py)